# error while deploying a project from jdeveloper 12c

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

When I try to deploy my project from jdeveloper 12c to a weblogic 12.x
I got this error:

```
[04:18:15 PM] [Deployer:149034]An exception occurred for task [Deployer:149026]deploy application habib on AdminServer.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.jps.wls.listeners.JpsApplicationLifecycleListener.
[04:18:15 PM] weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.jps.wls.listeners.JpsApplicationLifecycleListener
```

I have tried to search for `JpsApplicationLifecycleListener` in files using jdeveloper and it can't be found also, I tried to search for the `jps` listener in `weblogic-application.xml` but it can't be found this is what I found in `weblogic-application.xml`

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd"
                      xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application">
  <!--<listener>
    <listener-class>oracle.adf.share.weblogic.listeners.ADFApplicationLifecycleListener</listener-class>
  </listener>-->
  <!--<listener>
    <listener-class>oracle.mds.lcm.weblogic.WLLifecycleListener</listener-class>
  </listener>-->
  <library-ref>
    <library-name>adf.oracle.domain</library-name>
  </library-ref>
</weblogic-application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I figured out that the jdeveloper by default add the `JpsApplicationLifecycleListener` to the listener list in web logic that is because by default the configuration for weblogic deployment is like that:

[image]

you can solve this problem by simply change to `use the existing settings in weblogic-application.xml` like this image:

[image]

and the problem will be solved